# Angular: How to call component method from another component in different modules

Tags: angular

I am trying to call a method of A_Component owned by A_Module from B_Component owned by B_Module and am getting the following error as soon as I add A_Component as a parameter to the B_Component constructor:

> NullInjectorError: No provider for A_Component!

EDIT: The two components are not parent/child. Their modules are imported by app.module

(Code summarized for brevity)

A_Module:

```
import { A_Component } from '...'

@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    declarations: [A_Component],
    exports: [A_Component],
})

export class A_Module { }
```

B_Module:

```
import { A_Module } from '...'
import { B_Component } from '...'

@NgModule({
    imports: [A_Module],
    declarations: [B_Component]
})

export class B_Module { }
```

A_Component:

```
export class A_Component {
    someMethod() {...}
}
```

B_Component:

```
import { A_Component } from '...'

export class B_Component {

    constructor(public a_Component: A_Component)) {} //this param causes error

    callSomeMethod() {
        this.a_Component.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Is this not how to call component methods across modules? Is the only way to do this is with a service?

Comment: Is a_component a parent of B component in the view / template where you're using B component? Afaik, if you inject a component into another component, the Angular injector will look for that other component by traveling up the DOM tree from the point where the child component was instantiated. In other words, it will see if A_Component is a parent of B component, if not, it will see if its a parent of its parent component, and so on and so on. If they don't have a relationship like this in your view (the DOM), it won't know how to inject it. Share the code where you're using the components!

Comment: @diopside The two components are not parent children. Both modules are imported by app.module. You are correct, the only other times I've injected a component in a constructor was when the component was a parent of the child. I assumed I could do this with non-parent/child components as well.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation unfortunately doesn't make this part of Angular crystal-clear.

Comment: @Alex The Angular way is a shared service. This is the main point of making each component and independent item, and required as part of the optimization done at compilation.

Comment: Since this question a bit about modules interaction. There are cool article that allows you to understand module's scopes better - https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to [components interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction) official documentation.

You can call only methods of a component declared inside your component using [ViewChild](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild).

If you want to make two different component interact with each other - it should be done [via common service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).

*Updated after points from @diopside*

Comment: They most certainly can and its one of the most useful features of Angular!

Comment: See here for a simple example of how powerful/useful it can be - https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/04/09/developing-a-tabs-component-in-angular-2.html

Comment: @diopside You are right. Didn't know about such approach. However, it looks a bit 'inversed' for me ([when child injects parent](http://embed.plnkr.co/KU8eGM/)). [Dynamic components](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)  or [ContentChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren) looks more natural.

Comment: A lot of people don't, I didn't for a long time. I blame it on the crappy Angular documentation. For certain use cases its definitely the most elegant and simple approach. I use it frequently in situations where I have a single parent that contains a number of identical related child components (like tabs, lists, and other stuff). For anything other than direct parent-> child relationships, it can get messy