# How to call sibling component method in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular-services

I have a header component which is having autocomplete search, when the user search something and select one item from the suggestions dropdown, the body will change accordingly. In body 3 sections are there which is showing based on three different conditions. Here header and body are 2 different components, Hence how to trigger the function in body which is having some logic along with false and true variables. when the user select something from the autocomplete search dropdown. 
I am trying in a communication through service approach. 
**Header code**

```
<div class="docs-example-viewer-body custom-search" *ngIf="showSearch">
  <select class="search-dropdown">
    <option value="1">All</option>
    <option value="2">Brand</option>
    <option value="3">Molecule</option>
  </select>
  <app-auto-complete [mySearchData]="mySearchData" (onchange)="onchange($event)" (onsearchKey)="getOnsearchkey($event)"></app-auto-complete>
  <i class="material-icons">search </i>
</div>
```

**Body code**

```
<div *ngIf="aaa"> 123</div>
<div *ngIf="bbb"> 333</div>
```

**header component ts**

```
onChange(value) {
  this.planningService.changeOccured(value);
}
```

**planning service ts**

```
@Output() change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
changeOccured(value) {
  this.change.emit(value);
}
```

and trying to catch the event  from body component like this. But it is not triggering in body component. what is the issue 
    **body component ts**

```
onChange(value){
this.isSearchScreen = false;
this.isPlanListScreen = true;
this.isCreateScreen = false;
console.log('value',value)
this.myPlan.moleculeId = value.id;
this.selectedCombination = new SelectedCombination(value.brand,value.name);
this.planningService.getProductMapData(value.name).subscribe((data)=>{
  this.strengthANdPacks = data;
},(error)=>{
  console.log(error);
});
this.planningService.getAllPlans(value.id,false).subscribe((data)=>{
  this.allPlans = data;

},(error)=>{
  console.log(error);
});
}

ngOnInit(){
this.planningService.change.subscribe(value => {
  console.log('change occured')
 this.onChange(value)
});

}
```

I am unable to catch the event from service in body component. Can anyone please help me

Reference: https://medium.com/dailyjs/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb

Comment: try this, you can add it as directive and call its methods https://stackoverflow.com/a/50268682/4399281

Comment: What is the relation between your components ? Are they routed ? Are they parent/child ?

Comment: Sorry, it is actually, siblings component s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: How to call component method from another component in different modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144642/angular-how-to-call-component-method-from-another-component-in-different-module)

Comment: @Always_hungry Please check my edited question

Comment: is <app-auto-complete> the planning service ts?

Comment: <app-auto-complete> is a component

Answer (score 2):

To call a child component method from a parent component you can use ViewChild.

In your Parent class you would import the child component

```
import { ChildComponent } from './child-component.ts';
```

and then use something similar:

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent;
```

Then you will have access to your children component methods and properties:

```
this.childComponent.myMethod()
```

or

```
this.parentComponentValue = childComponent.property
```

Comment: Giving error AppHeaderComponent.html:63 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'myMethod' of undefined

Comment: That is the tile of your question - how to call a method in another component. To get the updated value you can then call in your parent component the updated property from your child component and assign the value of it to your parent component property.

Comment: @ThilakRaj - see you updated the question - can you post more code please? Parent and children class?

Comment: just to clarify, use this.childComponent.myMethod() in the component firing a function to its sibling.